# Loading the database with mysql (LBPH - Facerecognizer)

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

When loading a large database (mysql) I get an error: **Insufficient memory in OutOfMemoryError**.

I write in the first instance to the variable stringstream. Then run the function:

FileStorage fs(ss.str(), FileStorage::READ + FileStorage::MEMORY);
load(fs);

How can I solve this problem differently ?
The system is 32 bit ( server ).

P.S. Sory for ma English ;)

Comment: saving / loading the lbp facerec data in yml instead of xml will only take 1/3rd of the memory footprint

Comment: I load the Ibc facerec data as you suggested in yml. However, such solution does not meet my expectation and does not satisfy me